# How to setup doc_root path for php files?

Tags: php, path, absolute-path

I am trying to call files or folders like:

```
require('/functions.php');
$a = '/folder/';
```

but it wont work and keeps giving error "failed to open stream", i know i could modify "doc_root" from php.ini but not sure if that would be right and what exactly to modify.

Anyone could suggest pls?

thank you.

------ UPDATE -----
I am just trying to create a file inside subfolders using fopen:

```
$ourFileName = "/folder/subfolder/index.php"
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
```

but i dont want to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] because i want to use the same variable $ourFileName for building links

------UPDATE------ To make it even more clear, here is the code that does not work:

```
<?php 
$ourFileName = '/jobs/';
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName.'index.php', 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($ourFileHandle, 'hello world');  
fclose($ourFileHandle); 
?>
```

Comment: please show use your directory structure, we need to know exactly where the file your using `fopen` is located, and where the `/folder/subfolder/index.php` is located to make an accurate answer for you.

Comment: I think i already explained everything.. I dont want the files or folders to be dependable on its location, just to be able to call it form the root "/" and thats it. Try to execute the code to get it clear: <?php 
$ourFileName = '/jobs/';
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName.'index.php', 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($ourFileHandle, 'hello world'); 
fclose($ourFileHandle); 
?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about using :
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]

Comment: Depending on your PHP Configuration this is prone to Remote File Inclusions (RFI) and I advice against it unless securely sanitized and validated - http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/archive/1/476261/100/0/threaded

Answer (score 3):

To get the best possible root path you should define a constant in your view file, i.e (index.php) and you should make it cross platform compatible.

after the years working in PHP and multi platform applications I discovered the best method to do this is a combination of the following native PHP Functions and constants:

- define
- str_replace
- dirname
- `__FILE__`

Heres why we use the functions:

- The reason why we use define is to allow the document root to stay within the global scope
- The reason for `str_replace` is to change the slashes to be cross platform compatible
- The reason for `dirname` is to help the relative path to the root view file
- The reason for `__FILE__` is to discover the view file for `dirname`

We could use `__DIR__` for PHP5 but `__FILE__` is better as it would support previous versions of windows.

Fully combined you would have a valid relative path to your view file.

```
define("ROOT_PATH",str_repalce("\\","/",dirname(__FILE__)));
```

this would produce the perfect relative path to your index directory without the trailing slash, you should then include your files like so:

```
require_once ROOT_PATH . "/system/classes/some.class.php";
```

In windows both `/` and `\` are valid, and for other operating systems its just `/`, so generally you should always build your applications with the `/` as your directory separator.

Comment: Incorrect, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` varies on different platforms when it comes to trailing slashes, it also is empty within the command/shell environment.

Comment: Also `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is unreliable on some Apache configurations (specifically those using the `'VirtualDocumentRoot'` directive). So the `file_exists()` function that follows returns false.

Comment: keep it simple, dont need to be perfect

Comment: you know better mate... unfortunately i just see you talking and no one else commented about that method or rated your answer so i am not the one to teach you or say wow thats amazing etc... thanks for your help though!

Comment: @Alex: Actually RobertPitt is right, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is unreliable and you just don't have enough experience with PHP to know that.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your `functions.php` file is in the linux system root, that path will not work, as the first `/` character means "all the way to root".

If `functions.php` is in the same directory as your quoted file, try this:

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
$functions_absolute_path = $dir . '/functions.php';
require($functions_absolute_path);
```